# Object is null after model binding in Web API, using POSTMAN

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to learn Web API and created my first project as below.  I am testing it using postman. The post method works fine and I get response message – but the input received at the controller for the post action is null. What need to be done to get the post value in the controller?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        List<Comment> comments;

        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Get()
        {
            return comments;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public Comment Get(int id)
        {
            Comment c = comments[id-1];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Description))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return c;
        }

        // POST api/values
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Comment inputComment)
        {
            Comment c = new Comment();
            if (inputComment != null)
            {
                c.Description = inputComment.Description;
                c.ID = inputComment.ID;
            }
           //var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
           //return response;

            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Comment>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, c);
            response.Headers.Location=new System.Uri(Request.RequestUri,"/api/values/"+c.ID.ToString());
            return response;
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        public ValuesController()
        {
            comments = new List<Comment>();

            Comment comment1 = new Comment();
            comment1.ID = 1;
            comment1.Description = "Test1";

            Comment comment2 = new Comment();
            comment2.ID = 2;
            comment2.Description = "";

            comments.Add(comment1);
            comments.Add(comment2);

        }
    }
}
```

**POSTMAN Request/Response**

[image]

**POSTMAN Request Header**
[image]

**UPDATE**

After using 'raw' in the request body, it worked fine. In POSTMAN, when I clicked "Generate Code", it is now displaying correct headers.

[image]

Comment: Add [HttpPost] ontop of the method and [FromBody] before the attribute Comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Raw as body type instead of Form-data and input you JSON.

[image]